# Read Exce 2 1987 using .Net

Tags: excel

Does anyone know, how to read Excel 2 1987 file using .Net C#. I tried many assemblies which are available i.e Gembox Spreadsheet, OpenXml, ClosedXml, ExcelReader libraries but none of these tools are reading.

Actually, I have to change the Excel 2 1987 file format to Excel 2003.

Please share, if anyone have some information over it.

Many thanks!!

Comment: * Without using interop, it is working with interop but don't want interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working read it by stream reader and used ASCII table list which I found on http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ with the help of this I read the file and created new excel file using Gembox Spreadsheet.